# Look at decompiled source and ran across byte*

Tags: c#, .net

What in the world is a byte*?

example code:

```
byte* numPointer = (byte*)0;
byte* numPointer1 = (byte*)0;
uint* numPointer2 = (uint*)0;
```

Comment: * indicates a pointer type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A `byte *` (same thing as `byte*`) is a *pointer* to a `byte` variable. You almost never use pointers in C#, which is why you have never seen it before.

More specifically, a pointer is a variable that holds the memory location of another variable.

Regardless, don't worry about it unless you are planning to go into C++ or another native language.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Does C# support having a space between the type and the `*`? never knew that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain My VS auto-corrects the space out (kind of annoying actually), but it does compile fine.

Comment: If you are using Resharper you can make it add the space from the formatting setup "[Before unsafe pointer declaration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiwg4.png)"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the tip. Not using Resharper, but I don't use pointers enough to care anyways :)